# Read-only filesystem after adding userquota,groupquota to fstab

Tags: fstab, quota

When  I add option `userquota,groupquota` to the main (/) partition of my Debian 6 DirectAdmin server, it mounts that partition in read-only mode.

Wat  I did:

1. nano /etc/fstab
2. add `userquota,groupquota` after `errors=continue` in the 'options' column to the `/` mount-point
3. save the file and exit nano
4. reboot the server

On reboot it shows a lot of errors, all related to read-only filesystem.

Doen someone know what I perhaps did wrong? Thanks a lot!

Edit: my fstab looks like:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
# / was on /dev/vda1 during installation
UUID=aca09b50-554b-45b6-b3b6-e4444f1f80b6 /               ext3    errors=continue,userquota,groupquota 0       1
# swap was on /dev/vda5 during installation
UUID=628fb534-f3e4-4c44-93ad-f9f7992feff6 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct options are **usrquota** and **grpquota**. Also, after enabling quotas, you should run `quotacheck -uvg /path/to/your/device` in order to create the *aquota.{user,group}* files.

However, I would suggest to set up *journalled quota* as described in [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-journaled-quota-on-debian-lenny) tutorial.

Comment: Do you know if that works with DirectAdmin?

Comment: Journaled quota? Yes, it works.